# How do I retrieve the latest foreign key related items by group?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class LogEntry(models.Model)
     employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
     log_type = models.CharField(max_length=2)
     entry_date = models.DateTimeField()
     log_data = models.TextField()
```

In this case, the log_type is a 2 alpha code (there are many options).  For a given employee, I would like to retrieve the latest LogEntry for all log_types that the given employee has created.  I have seen examples using annotate to grab the latest for all employees, or the latest for all log_types, but not one that restricts on one field, while annotating on another.  Everything I have tried thus far has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `.last()` method, it returns last created record by id.

```
logentry = Employe.objects.get(name="your employe name")\
                               .logentry_set.filter(log_type="log type code").last()
```

Comment: The issue here is that I would need to know the log type codes.  I want a query that grabs the latest of all log type codes the user has entered.  (The user may have entered 1 log types, 10, or 50).